# How does getenv() get the parameters of the http request parsed by nginx?

Tags: php, c++, nginx, fastcgi

When writing CGI program for spawn-fcgi, use `getenv()` to get environment variables, that is, the parameters set by `fastcgi_param` command in **fastcgi.conf**. but when I use the env command output on the terminal in Linux, I can't find the corresponding environment variable. Why?

[fastcgi_param](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html)

> Sets a parameter that should be passed to the FastCGI server. The value can contain text, variables, and their combination. These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no fastcgi_param directives defined on the current level.

Since it says that these parameters are passed by nginx to the FastCGI server, how does `getenv()` get these parameters? I learned that `getenv()` is used to obtain environment variables. So did spawn-fcgi create these temporary environment variables according to fastcgi.conf when ngnix passed dynamic requests?

Comment: All operating systems with environment variables allow process creation or running where these are passed one way or another. For example of POSIX system (like Linux and macOS) the `exec` family of functions have variants where the environment variables can be passed as an argv-like array.

Comment: Yes, I tried setting the environment variable version of exec, and it did. However, I checked the source code of spawn-fcgi. It uses execv and execl, but neither of them will change the environment variables inherited by the child process. In addition, the value of the environment variable of each subprocess will change with the change of the http request, which is not fixed. So I want to ask how to do this? Probably give a thought.@Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fastcgi` library directly modifies the `environ` variable of the program, simulating a new environment after accepting a request. See: https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/fcgi2/blob/874b148dfeadf8ebadff89cf228e63f836e509a3/doc/FCGI_Accept.3

> After accepting a new request, FCGI_Accept assigns new values
> to the global variables `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, and `environ`.
> After FCGI_Accept returns, these variables have the same
> interpretation as on entry to a CGI program.

And https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/environ.html

Answer (score 1):

Each process has its own set of environment variables.

When a new process gets created it inherits the environment variables from its parent process.

The `env` command gets started by your terminal process, it inherits the terminal's environment variables and that's what it shows you.

As you know, your terminal does not get started by spawn-fcgi. Although nobody knows which came first, the chicken or the egg, it's fairly certain that your terminal process does not get started by spawn-fcgi. And that's why your terminal does not show the environment variables that spawn-fcgi sets and are inherited by the processes that spawn-fcgi, itself, starts.

Comment: Yes, I just learned some knowledge about inheritance of environment variables between parent and child processes. I also know that my cgi process was created by spawn-fcgi using fork-exec. But just now I went to check the source code of spawn-fcgi, which uses execv and execl, and does not involve making the child process inherit different environment variables. So it is only possible that the cgi process inherits these environment variables from the spawn-fcgi process by default. Is that right?

Comment: Someone in the chain of parent processes set these environment variables, that's the only mechanism by which they come from.

Comment: So how does the child process of spawn-fcgi modify the values of its related environment variables according to different http requests? My cgi program does not write relevant code. Can the parent process also modify the value of the environment variable of the child process?

Comment: Environment variables are just lists of strings. When a new child process gets created the parent process specifies the list of strings that comprise the new process's environment variables. It's just like having your own array of strings in your own program, and then you have some code that modifies this array of strings and then passes this array to some function. Abracadabra: that function now receives a modified list of "environment variables".

Comment: Yes, I remember that environment variables are just strings in the program. However, the child process created by spawn-fcgi will not be destroyed, so new environment variables cannot be passed by creating child processes.
In fact, Nginx parses the new http protocol, and the created child process of spawn-fcgi will update its existing environment variables accordingly. How did this happen? And the child process does not update the code of the environment variable.

Comment: Your own code can change it's environment variables by calling setenv or putenv. The same thing happens here. Arrangements are made to do that. Your code doesn't run continuously. After servicing each request it waits for the next one. As part of it, the internal mechanics of passing in the next request also involve updating the environment variables.